# gcc shell command execution in php

Tags: php

Following is the php program written and tried to execute

```
<?php
$v=shell_exec("gcc");
echo "hi".$v;
?>
```

When I run this php program through browser no outputs are coming.

However for the following program, it displays the list of files available in the folder

```
<?php
$v=shell_exec("ls");
echo $v;
?>
```

Even it works for ifconfig, ./file and cat command but it is not considering the gcc or cc.

If I write the command in terminal gcc, it displays fatal and file missing warning. The same warning message must be displayed in the browser when I run the php code containing the shell_exec. But it is not.

The linux server machine contains the gcc.

can any one solve the problem?

Comment: doesn't gcc need a file to compile?

Comment: It needs. I tried with filename also. However for testing gcc is enough

Answer (score 0):

Use the following this will work , actually we have to redirect the standard error to standard output , 2 is standard error and 1 is standard output and & is used only for the file descript

```
<?php
$v=shell_exec("gcc 2>&1");
echo "hi".$v;
?>
```